# calling function inside react functional component from outside

Tags: reactjs

I'm using [EEL](https://github.com/samuelhwilliams/Eel) for a python app, if I need call a python

with Eel I can call javascript functions directly from python

```
eel.expose(my_javascript_function);
function my_javascript_function(a, b, c, d) {
  if (a < b) {
    console.log(c * d);
  }
}
can be called from the Python side like this...

print('Calling Javascript...')
eel.my_javascript_function(1, 2, 3, 4)  # This calls the Javascript function
```

now...I'm interested in update my react inner state (using hooks) through python, I think that I could write a function inside my Component and update the state from here, I know that this is not the "react way" but is there a way to achieve this? I think that using useImperativeHandle could works but I'm not sure

thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

this was more simple than I thought, just set to the component as a property,

```
function MyReactComponent(){
 useEffect(() => {
        MyReactComponent.exposedFunction = ()=>{
           //you can even set state here
        }
        // or expose in the window object
        window.MyReactComponent = MyReactComponent
    }, [])



}
```

and then call like

```
MyReactComponent.exposedFunction()
```

again, **this solution is not following the react style and principles but it works if you need to integrate this to Eel or to any other solution**

Answer (score 0):

For others looking for an answer, eel has a a specific expose method for dealing with the compilation steps that come with frameworks like react.

From Eel [Example 07](https://github.com/ChrisKnott/Eel/tree/master/examples/07%20-%20CreateReactApp):

> Use window.eel.expose(func, 'func') to circumvent npm run build code mangling

So instead of
`eel.expose(my_javascript_function);`, it would become `window.eel.expose(my_javascript_function, 'my_javascript_function');`